# how to draw a circle like this and figures like this?

Tags: tikz-graphdrawing

[image]

This is a handwritten note that I'm currently working on, can someone help me with the code in LaTeX

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```tex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=gray,dashed] (1,1) circle (0.75);
\draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,2);
\draw[->] (-2,0) -- (2,0);
\node[fill, circle, inner sep=1pt, label={below:$x$}] at (1,1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

As general introductory pointers, `\draw` is good for basic shapes like lines/arrows, circles, etc. while nodes (`\node`) are useful for text. The optional arguments in the brackets after these commands (`fill`, `dashed`, etc.) give specifications/modifiers for the object being drawn. For example, `\draw[dashed]` will result in a dashed shape.

I would recommend consulting the [TikZ/PGF manual](https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf) for great help with basic TikZ and more information on these modifiers. I've found it useful to Ctrl+F through when I find answers here on SE using commands I'm unfamiliar with. Good luck!

Comment: can you help me with shading the axes between x-e and x+e?

Answer (score 0):

As starting point:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                patterns.meta}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
       > = Straight Barb,
P/.style = {pattern={Lines[angle=45, distance={2pt}, line width=0.1pt]},
            pattern color=gray}
                        ]
\draw[->]   (-1,0) node[above] {$\mathbb{R}$}  -- (2.2,0);
\foreach \i[count=\x from 0] in {x-\varepsilon, x, x+\varepsilon}
    \draw (0.2+0.8*\x,2pt) -- ++ (0,-4pt) node[below] {$\i$};
\path[P] (0.2,0) rectangle (1.8,0.2);

    \begin{scope}[yshift=-33mm]
\draw[P]  (1,1) circle[radius=0.8];
\draw[->] (-1,0) node[above=8mm] {$\mathbb{R}^2$} -- (2.2,0);
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,2);
\node[fill, circle, inner sep=1pt, label=below:$x$] at (1,1) {};
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]